# search and count occurances of a word in a textbox string

Tags: vb.net

Right now I have two textboxes. One is the input and the other the text string. It functions perfectly. Is there a way to get rid of the input box and have the "searched" word in the code so when I hit a button it gives the result.

```
Private Function FindWords(ByVal TextSearched As String, ByVal Paragraph As String) As Integer

    Dim location As Integer = 0
    Dim occurances As Integer = 0
    Do
        location = TextSearched.IndexOf(Paragraph, location)
        If location <> -1 Then
            occurances += 1
            location += Paragraph.Length
        End If
    Loop Until location = -1
    Return occurances
End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text ' display result
    Label2.Text = FindWords(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
    ' MsgBox("The word " & TextBox2.Text & " has occured " & FindWords(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) & " times!!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Um, you mean you want to hardcode your input? Something like `Label2.Text = FindWords("word", TextBox2.Text)` perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Perhaps, I can't  seem to implement this correctly to get it to work? if I just replace the label2 line it seems to be stuck in a loop or something.

Comment: It would be better to use Regex for this. Here's a simple solution: `Regex.Matches(TextBox2.Text, Regex.Escape(TextBox1.Text)).Count`

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of small problems that you'll might see of you turn on option strict in your project's compile settings. Your function returns an integer. To properly assign it to a textbox label, you should really add **.ToString** to the end of the assignment like this

```
Label2.Text = FindWords(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text).ToString
```

So leaving you code as you wrote it, in this sub, you just want to pass a string as the parameter for the text to find?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text ' display result
    Label2.Text = FindWords(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
    ' MsgBox("The word " & TextBox2.Text & " has occured " & FindWords(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) & " times!!")
End Sub
```

Just change it to this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    dim searchString as string="Hello" 'or whatever string you want to use
    Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text ' display result
    Label2.Text = FindWords(searchString, TextBox2.Text)
    ' MsgBox("The word " & TextBox2.Text & " has occured " & FindWords(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text) & " times!!")
End Sub
```

but it might be better to change it a bit more so that your function only gets executed once if you want to display a messagebox with the number of occurences - like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    dim searchCount as Integer
    dim searchString as string="Hello" 'or whatever string you want to use
    Label1.Text = TextBox2.Text ' display result
    searchCount = FindWords(searchString, TextBox2.Text)
    Label2.Text = searchcount.ToString
    ' MsgBox("The word " & TextBox2.Text & " has occured " & searchcount.Tostring & " times!!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Very much for the information.  Everything is working perfectly.